# getting this code to update on select option change

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!--js-->

function changeValue(dropdown,source) {
    var option = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    if (option == '1' && source==0) {
        var total = 20;
        $("span").text(total);
        $('.balance').attr({"min":0, "max":total}).on('input', function() {
            var value = parseInt(this.value);
            var otherInputs = $('.balance').not(this);
            var remainderDiv;
            var remainder, sum;
            if (isNaN(value)) {
                value = 0;
            } else if (value > total) {
                value = total;
            } else if (value < 0) {
             value = 0;
            }
            this.value = value;
            remainder = total - value;
            remainderDiv = remainder / otherInputs.length;
            sum = value;
            $.each(otherInputs, function(input) {
             sum += Number(otherInputs[input].value);
            });
            if (sum > total) {
             otherInputs.val(remainderDiv);
            }
        });
    }else if (option == '2' && source==0) {
        var total = 20;
        $("span").text(total);
        $('.balance').attr({"min":0, "max":total}).on('input', function() {
            var value = parseInt(this.value);
            var otherInputs = $('.balance').not(this);
            var remainderDiv;
            var remainder, sum;
            if (isNaN(value)) {
                value = 0;
            } else if (value > total) {
                value = total;
            } else if (value < 0) {
             value = 0;
            }
            this.value = value;
            remainder = total - value;
            remainderDiv = remainder / otherInputs.length;
            sum = value;
            $.each(otherInputs, function(input) {
                sum += Number(otherInputs[input].value);
            });
            if (sum > total) {
                otherInputs.val(remainderDiv);
            }
        });
    }
}   

<!--html-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="changeValue(this,0)">
    <option value="1">1-person</option>
    <option value="2">2-10 group</option>
</select>


<input type="number" class="balance">
<input type="number" class="balance">

<!--html-->
```

that's the way i want it to stay with the options and if statements. The reason i want it that way is because the fields are dynamically added. So if you could just add a function to that existing code to let it change the value when i change the select option that would be great. THE CODE UP TOP IS WORKING PERFECT IT JUST NEEDS WHAT I AM ASKING.

Comment: Really not understanding what you actually need. Please elaborate

Comment: @Umair Farooq  ok if you copy the code i have and run it you will see whats happening when you change the select option. So if you select 1-person and then select 2-10 group the value set for 1-person remains in the fields and wont change dynamically.

Comment: To what value you wanna change it dynamically to ?

Comment: @ Umair Farooq  https://jsfiddle.net/tripplex/ha4Lm7o8/ check that out you will then see what i want. you realize when you change the select option the value cannot be changed in the  field it retains its previous value. its like the memory needs to be flushed or something.

Comment: That fiddle is just showing max of 1 on both inputs. When there is one is first field, if I try to put more than 0 (max 1) in second field, the first field gets 0. I am still not sure what you are meaning by dynamically changing the value. Please look at your question and edit it to properly explain what problem you are facing

Comment: @Umair Farooq check the fiddler  that's the way it suppose to work if you can read through the code and understand it. read through what i commented up top and you'll understand whats happening.

Comment: So as far as I can understand, On selecting option 1, you want both input to have a max of 1 min of 0, on option 2 selection you want max of 15 and min of 2 and on option 3 selection max of 25 and min of 16.
So if I entered 1 in the first input box, and select 2nd option the input should get to 2 (min value of second option)

Comment: i just want what you said last to work"So if I entered 1 in the first input box, and select 2nd option the input should get to 2 (min value of second option)". the rest of the code is working the way i want it to.

Comment: check the js fiddler again i add some comment in the html section. i dont want the code to change i just woulde like if you could just add a function in it to let it do what i want.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tripplex/ha4Lm7o8/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there were some inconsistencies in your code.

You were setting the on input event every time when you change selection of the dropdown. In jquery that is bad because it does not overwrite the previous event but it adds one more event to that element. Imagine changing the dropdown 100 times.

So first of all what I did is that add the input event on each element containing 'sex' as class in `$(document).ready` function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sex').on('input', function() {
        var option = $("#dropdown")[0].selectedIndex;
        //your other code for balancing the inputs
    });
 });
```

Now what I will be doing in the `changeValue()` function you wrote is just setting the min and max value of the input elements and also balancing their division so that the the sum of both (maybe more than two in future) will not exceed the total of current case.

```
function changeValue(dropdown,source) {
    if (source == 0){

        var caseNo = dropdown.selectedIndex;
        var minValue = 0, maxValue = 1;

        if(caseNo === 2)
            maxValue = 15;
        else if(caseNo === 3)
            maxValue = 25;

        $(".sex").attr({"min": minValue, "max": maxValue});

        $.each($(".sex"), function(){
            //your other code for balancing the inputs
        });
    }
}
```

We know that min value will always be 0 because any of male and female input can be 0 in any case. We are only concerned with the max value. So I just find the required the max value according to case no and then set the textboxes min and max values according to both.

Now this line of code

```
$.each($(".sex"), function(){
    //your other code for balancing the inputs
});
```

It will be used to balance the inputs whenever the selection of dropdown is changed.

As the same code will be using over and over again so I made a function named `balanceValues()`

Here is its definition

```
function balanceValues(caseNo, elementId){
    var value = parseInt($("#" + elementId).val());
    var otherInputs = $(".sex").not($("#" + elementId));
    var remainderDiv;
    var remainder, sum;

    var total = 1;

    if(caseNo === 2)
        total = 15;
    else if(caseNo === 3)
        total = 25;

    if (isNaN(value)) {
        value = 0;
    } else if (value > total) {
        value = total;
    } else if (value < 0) {
        value = 0;
    }

    $("#" + elementId).val(value);

    remainder = total - value;
    remainderDiv = remainder / otherInputs.length;
    sum = value;
    $.each(otherInputs, function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });

    if (sum > total) {
        otherInputs.val(remainderDiv);
    }
  }
```

Almost all of the code is same as was yours but I made it reusable. You just need to pass caseNo and element id on which input is changed. For the selection change event we will call this function for all inputs.

So now the `$(document).ready` function will be like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sex').on('input', function() {
        var option = $("#dropdown")[0].selectedIndex;
        balanceValues(option, this.id);
    });
 });
```

And in `changeValue()` function the line of code will in which I put a comment earlier will be like this.

```
$.each($(".sex"), function(){
    balanceValues(dropdown.selectedIndex, $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

I have tested the code at my end and its working fine. Hope this solves your problem.